# Can not move widgets in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to learn tkinter, but I got a problem and I can`t move forward from this point. I wanted to make just a simple GUI with one button, unfortunately, I am not able to move that button ( being always displayed in the most left upper corner).

This is the code that I used :

```
class App(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.master.title('GUI')
    quitbttn = Button(self, text='quit')
    quitbttn.grid(row=3, column=5)

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Although, I found this snippet of code on the iternet, and it is working perfectly, the only difference being that `pack()` is used instead of `grid()` :

```
class Window(Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()
def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("GUI")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    quit_button = Button(self, text='quit')
    quit_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)



root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to be able to use grid as well. 
Any advice is being apreciated. Thank you!

Comment: in grid() empty rows/columns have no size - so even if you use `row=3` then row 1 and 2 have width zero and you see no difference. The same with columns. You have to set default size for rows and columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you cannot move the button is because you only have one element.

```
quitbttn.grid(row=3, column=5)
```

This part of the script basically says that the button should be placed a third row down and in the fifth space along.  Since you have no other elements in the window it does not move the button at all.  This is because all the 2 rows and 4 columns are all equal to 0 so the first place it packs is in the top left corner.

Using the `.pack()` function allows you move the button without the need of any other button in the window.

If you added another button you would then be able to move around the first button in three different places.

Note that you cannot use the `.pack()` and `.grid()` functions in the same window.

Comment: @robertg  No problem. : )